# Remove Hyperledger fabric added Peer

Tags: distributed, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

Consider there are three organizations on the channel and one of them are no longer in business with the other two.

I found there's way to revoke the user certificates from accessing, but no way to remove (reject) peer from existing channel.

Answer (score 0):

In fabric 1.1, they introduced the configtxlator tool in order to simplify the management of organisations on an already deployed network.
You can retrieve the current configuration, change it and it computes a config delta and create a channel update transaction.

There is a tutorial from IBM, which explains how to add a new organisation. Probably you can work from this to find how to remove an org.
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-add-an-organization-to-your-hyperledger-fabric-blockchain/index.html

Comment: Thanks. BTW, have you tried it? I found error happen when following the instruction of the document. I've created another thread to discuss it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49769158/hyperledger-fabric-v1-1-add-organization